# Bound from Skewness

Tags: probability

Let $P \sim Poisson(\lambda)$.

Let $X \sim P^2 - P$.

By Chebyshev's inequality we have : $$\forall k.\ \Pr(X \in [\mu - k \sigma\ ;\  \mu + k \sigma]) \geq 1 - \frac{1}{k^2}$$

But this doesn't learn us anything on $X$ knowing  $X \in [\mu - k \sigma; \mu + k \sigma]$. I would like to be sure that all the mass isn't on the same side, i.e. : $$\Pr(X \in [\mu \ ;\ \mu + k \sigma]) > f(k) > 0 $$
I guess such a lower bound needs assumption on skewness (and may be on others moments), but I can't find any relevant inequality online.

[image: picture]

I am looking for a lower bound for the probability corresponding to the red area.

Comment: If you suspect there is *not* such an inequality, something to try would be to see if you can cook up a distribution with arbitrary skewness without any mass in $[\mu,\mu+k\sigma]$.

Comment: Thanks, but I think there is such inequality. X distribution added.

Comment: Picture added !